# How to manage routes with Internationalization in CakePHP?

Tags: cakephp, internationalization, cakephp-4.x

My website will manage two languages, French (default language) and Dutch.
In French, I think I don't need to show the language parameter in the URL, so I want to display it for Dutch only (eg. myapp.com/nl/). Currently my routes are not working properly, not sure if I am using lang parameter the right way.
I am a rookie with CakePHP so I did the below as per documentation :

Header.php (*I think there is an issue here...*)

```
<?php if (!$this->request->getParam('lang')) : ?>
        <?= $this->Html->link('<i class="fas fa-globe"></i> Nederlands', ['lang' => 'nl'], ['class' => 'btn ms-lg-4 btn-primary btn-sm float-end float-lg-start mt-3 mt-lg-0', 'escape' => false]) ?>
<?php else : ?>
        <?= $this->Html->link('<i class="fas fa-globe"></i> Français', ['lang' => ''], ['class' => 'btn ms-lg-4 btn-primary btn-sm float-end float-lg-start mt-3 mt-lg-0', 'escape' => false]) ?>
<?php endif ?>
```

appController.php

```
public function beforeFilter(EventInterface $event) {
    # We check if we have a language set
    if ($this->request->getParam('lang')) {
        I18n::setLocale($this->request->getParam('lang'));
    } else {
        # If we don't have one, we will set the default one (in my case it's French)
        I18n::setLocale('fr');
    }
}
```

routes.php

```
 $builder
    ->connect(
        '/',
        ['controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'home']
    );

$builder
    ->connect(
        '{lang}/',
        ['controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'home']
    )
    ->setPersist(['lang']);

$builder
    ->connect(
        '/{lang}/{controller}/{action}/*', 
        []
    )
    ->setPatterns([
        'lang' => '[a-z]{2}'
    ])
    ->setPersist(['lang']);

$builder
    ->connect(
        '/{lang}/{controller}/{action}/{id}', 
        []
    )
    ->setPatterns([
        'lang' => '[a-z]{2}',
        'id' => '\d+'
    ])
    ->setPersist(['lang'])
    ->setPass(['id']);

$builder
    ->connect(
        '/{lang}/{controller}/{action}/{slug}', 
        []
    )
    ->setPatterns([
        'lang' => '[a-z]{2}',
        'slug' => '[a-z0-9-_]+'
    ])
    ->setPersist(['lang'])
    ->setPass(['slug']);
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your Header.php

```php
<?php
    $langList = ['fr', 'nl'];
    // Remove lang from current URL
    $hereWithoutLang = preg_replace('#^/(' . implode('|', $langList) . ')#', '', $this->request->getRequestTarget());
?>

<?= $this->Html->link(
    '<i class="fas fa-globe"></i> Nederlands',
    '/nl' . $hereWithoutLang,
    ['class' => 'btn ms-lg-4 btn-primary btn-sm float-end float-lg-start mt-3 mt-lg-0', 'escape' => false]) ?>

<?= $this->Html->link(
    '<i class="fas fa-globe"></i> Français',
    empty($hereWithoutLang) ? '/' : $hereWithoutLang,
    ['class' => 'btn ms-lg-4 btn-primary btn-sm float-end float-lg-start mt-3 mt-lg-0', 'escape' => false]) ?>
```